# Multiple excel files - Python

Tags: python, excel

I am so new at python that I don’t know how to start my code.

I have 26 excel files:
File1
File2
File3
File4
Etc...

And I have one template.xlsx file that has formulas in it.

I want to create a for loop that will open File1 copy all the data inside sheet1, (A1:N) N cell always varies in range.

Then open the template file and paste the copied data to sheet1 (B13:O). Then do a save as “new file 1”.

Then repeat this process 25 more times. Open file2 copy data from sheet1 (A1:N), open template paste data to sheet1 (B13:O) save as “new file 2”.

I’ve already downloaded appropriate packages.

Comment: Hi Kristen! People on SO usually want to see some of the code you have tried yourself so they can help you more easily with your problem. So you may want to add some of your code you tried. :)

Comment: The easiest way to write Excel files using Python would be to use an existing library. I personally have used [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) before. I recommend you'll have a look at this and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I don't have any code, because I don't know how to start, i'm literally brand new at python never used it.

Comment: put all files in a folder  , loop through all files in folder, read into a dataframe , keep a consoframe , append the dataframe to consoframe... search all steps in google adding python in start.... all the best